How to give user permission to access project instance in gcloud CLI?
I am attempting to migrate a Google Cloud Firebase project from one organization to another and I've completed the official checklist and have all of the IAM policies and organization policies in place. However, when I attempt to execute the migration using the CLI with the following terminal command...
gcloud beta projects move some-project-abc123 --organization 1307034340429

I am met with the following error:

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.projects.move) User [my@email.address] does not have
permission to access projects instance [some-project-abc123] (or it may
not exist): The caller does not have permission

Is there a special IAM policy that I must grant this user in order to access the project's instance through the gcloud CLI? This particular user has the highest-level of access within the organization and over the project itself (organization administrator, owner, project creator, project mover, etc.).

Here are the roles that you need [1]:


Project IAM Admin (roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin) on the project that you want to migrate between organization resources.

Project Mover (roles/resourcemanager.projectMover) on the project's parent resource (folder or organization resource).

If the destination resource is a folder: Project Mover (roles/resourcemanager.projectMover) on the destination resource.

If the destination resource is an organization resource: Project Creator (roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator) on the destination resource.



You may also add this:
Organization Policy Admin (roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin) on both the source and destination organization resources.
Next, you need to configure organization policies on the Source and Destination Organizations.
[1]. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/assign-iam-roles#permissions_move

This looks like an AI response. What you posted is the very checklist I said I already completed.

lol. How is it AI? I literally replied the two important steps that you need plus an additional role that you can assign that you didn't mention
